# How to get location information (lat, long) in react?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation

When I try to get the latitude and longitude using geolocation API in react, it only can get the latitude. The longitude stays null.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            latitude: null,
            longitutde: null,
            
        };
        this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
        this.getCoordinates = this.getCoordinates.bind(this);
      }

      getLocation(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getCoordinates, this.handleLocationError);     
      }

      getCoordinates(position){
        this.setState({ 
            latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
          })
      } 

<Button onClick={this.getLocation} className="mt-1 loc-button"variant="outline-info" >Get current location</Button>
                        <p>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</p>
                        <p>Longitude: {this.state.longitutde}</p>
```

Comment: `"longitutde" !== "longitude"`

Answer (score 1):

It is just a typo.

change:

```
<p>Longitude: {this.state.longitutde}</p>
```

to

```
<p>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</p>
```

AND also
change:

```
longitutde: null,
```

to

```
longitude : null
```

And it will work.